# How to find or replace lost item?

Tags: tabletop-simulator

I accidentally tossed an important item off the table. For whatever reason it didn't reappear on the middle of the table. Maybe I put it into a bag accidentally. Is there any way to find or recreate the item?

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the game
2. Leave to the main menu
3. Open a fresh version of the mod
4. Find the item in question
5. Right-click on the item, then *Save Object*
6. Quit back to the Main menu
7. Load the original game
8. In the top menu choose Objects > Saved Objects
9. Find the item in the browser and click on it to spawn it